# Peano axioms proof

Tags: proof-writing, peano-axioms

Given that $K$ is an ordered field satisfying the least upper bound property and $1$ as the multiplicative identity, the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}_K$ in $K$ is defined as: $1 \in \mathbb{N}_K$ and $N + 1 \in \mathbb{N}_K$ if $N \in \mathbb{N}_K$. In this case, $N = 1 + ... + 1 \}$ $N$ times. Show that $\mathbb{N}_K$ satisfies the Peano axioms.

I am new to analysis and was not really taught about the Peano axioms and can't seem to find anything on the web about exactly what I need to prove in this problem. Can someone please briefly list and/or describe the axioms that need to be shown in order to complete the above proof? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You can find the list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). To show that any of those axioms are satisfied by $\mathbb{N}_K$ you'll want to use the fact that $K$ is a completely ordered field, i.e., going back to the field axioms, etc..

Comment: @Hayden It starts with "$0$ is a natural number" however in the book I use, it suggests that they start from $1$?

Comment: Yeah, whether $0$ is considered a natural number is a bit up to personal preference. Within the first-order axiomatization, replace the first axiom with $\forall x ~(S(x) \neq 1)$, the third axiom with $\forall x ~(x+1 = S(x))$, the fifth axiom with $\forall x ~(x \cdot 1 = x)$, and in the induction axiom schema, replace $0$ with $1$. Although I haven't checked the details carefully, any model of this modified system of axioms should arise as the set of all nonzero elements of a model of the original system, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are allowed to sum numbers, and if you are in the natural numbers, this is quite natural. And define the operation $S(x) = x+1$ to be it, then we have to believe:

1. $S(x) = S(y) $, meaning that our $x$ equals $y$, so $S$ is injective;
2. 1 is the only element, that doesn't succed any other, then there is no $x$ in natural numbers such that $S(x) = 1$;
3. Suppose there is a subset of natural numbers with 1 inside it, then if in this subset there is another, then it's because $S(x) \in X$, and so, this subset is the natural numbers set.

Comment: Are these the only three things to be shown?

Comment: First, I want to know why $N= 1+1+1+ ... +1$ in this case above as you described?